# Convert utf8/mixed to utf8 and strip non ascii chars

Tags: php, imap

How to convert utf8 strings to iso 8859-1?

Why doesn't `imap_mime_header_decode` detect the `utf8` coded string?

I need to remove all 4 byte unicode chars so the string fits in mysql utf8

Have tried this but it doesn't work

```
$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```

## code

```
$input = '=?UTF-8?Q?=c3=b8en?=';
echo "$input\n";
$output = '';
foreach(imap_mime_header_decode($input) as $element){
    if($element->charset == 'utf-8'){
        echo "utf8 charset = $element->text\n";
        $output .= $element->text;
    }
    else{
        echo "default charset = $element->text\n";
        $output .= $element->text;
    }
}
// Here output should be iso 8859-1
echo "$output\n";
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zæøåA-ZÆØÅ0-9 \-\.,:]/', '', $output);
// Back to utf8
$string = utf8_encode($string);
echo "$string\n";
```

## output

```
=?UTF-8?Q?=c3=b8en?=
default charset = Ã¸en
Ã¸en
en
```

Comment: In my testing, it is not removed. See also https://3v4l.org/UiauT

Comment: Strange.. When testing on another server is works like it should.. output `øen`.. is there something I have overlooked in the config?

Comment: Are you testing in the browser? Is it possible you are seeing a character encoding issue in the page output due to what encoding the web server thinks it's sending? If you test that code in the console via `php -a` on the faulty server does it produce the correct output?

Comment: no.. testing in putty.. (cronjob)

Comment: Could maybe be a client character encoding thing with the SSH session. Check `strlen($string)` - is it 2 characters or 3 (indicating one has not printed)?

Comment: `strlen($string)` output `2`

Comment: This works for me when the file is encoded as UTF8.

Comment: Your search string (`$string = 'øen';`) is still utf8 though and your file isnt.

Comment: @chris85 you are right.. have edited my code and added some :) I was sure it was converted to iso 8859-1 in the first part

Comment: Why do you need to go to `iso 8859-1`?

Comment: I need to remove all 4 byte unicode chars so the string fits in mysql with utf8

Comment: Moving to iso8859-1 will remove a hell of a lot more than just the 4 byte UTF-8 characters.

Comment: @GolezTrol, have modified my code a little.. I think you maybe misunderstood what I was trying.. First I want to convert all strings to iso and then convert it back to utf8

Comment: iso8859-1 only supports 256 different characters.  You really want to blow away everything else, of the 100k characters of unicode?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution.. First it converts to `utf-8` (including 4 byte unicode chars), then converts to `iso 8859-1` and then stripping unwanted chars and then finally encoding to `utf-8`

:D

```
private function strip_non_ascii($string){
    $return = '';
    if(preg_match('/^=\?(iso-8859-1|utf-8)\?q\?/i', $string)){
        $return = str_replace('_',' ', mb_decode_mimeheader($string));
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/^(iso-8859-1\'\')(.*)$/i', $string, $matches)){
        $return = utf8_encode(rawurldecode($matches[2]));
    }
    else{
        $return = imap_utf8($string);
    }

    return utf8_encode(preg_replace('/[^a-zæøåA-ZÆØÅ0-9 \-\.,:]/', '', utf8_decode($return)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to convert the special characters to HTML entities. You can optionally specify an encoding of the source string, which is encouraged to specify. In your case, this would be 'UTF-8'. The HTML entities are safe to store in a database and are safe to output in their escaped form, although you may choose to use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to convert as many characters as possible back to an encoding of your choice.